# Django ValidationError when deleting queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am writing a Django command to delete data older than x days from my app.

The filtering is made using the following:

`qs = Data.objects.filter(date_created__lte=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=days_del))`

With `days_del` being an integer and `date_created` a `DateTimeField`.

When trying to either print this queryset, or calling `.delete()` on it result in a `JSONDecodeError` and `ValidationError`. I don't really get why this happens or how I can prevent it trying to decode JSON fileds in this case.

Note that I am using the `jsonfield` pypi package and the Data model has a `JSONField`.

It is possible that some data are stalled and causing the problem (see traceback), is there a way to ignore the validation and proceed with the deletion anyway?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonfield/fields.py", line 83, in pre_init
    return json.loads(value, **self.load_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 464 (char 463)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/webapps/myproj/server/mirrors/management/commands/data_cleanup.py", line 39, in handle
    qs.delete()
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 616, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 191, in collect
    reverse_dependency=reverse_dependency)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 89, in add
    if not objs:
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 583, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 502, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.attname, val)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonfield/subclassing.py", line 43, in __set__
    obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.pre_init(value, obj)
  File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonfield/fields.py", line 85, in pre_init
    raise ValidationError(_("Enter valid JSON"))
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Enter valid JSON']
```

I am deleting a lot of data at the same time, maybe there's a better way to handle this. Anyway fixing the old staled data is not an option here.

Thanks

---

Here is the command file:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from oauth2_provider.models import Application
from django.utils import timezone

import pytz
from datetime import timedelta

from confluence_core.models import Data



class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete data older than given days'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("-d", "--days", type=int, dest='days', required=True, help="Days limit")
        parser.add_argument("-c", "--confirm", action='store_true', dest='confirm', default=False, required=False, help="Confirm before deletion")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        days_del = options['days']
        do_delete = False

        qs = Data.objects.filter(date_created__lte=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=days_del))

        if qs.count() > 0:

            if options['confirm']:
                print(f"{qs.count():,} data entries will be deleted.")
                ret = input("Confirm ? (y/n)\n")
                if ret in ['y', 'Y', 'yes']:
                    do_delete = True
            else:
                do_delete = True

            if do_delete is True:
                print(f"Deleting {qs.count():,} data entries...")
                qs.delete()
            else:
                print("Not deleting anything.")

        else:
            print("No data to delete.")

        print("Done.")
```

Comment: Can you add `/mirrors/management/commands/data_cleanup.py` file ?

Comment: Updated, don't think it's useful though because there's only just a delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the ORM force loads the queryset when deleting, cf:

```
File "/root/virtualenvs/myproj-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 89, in add
if not objs:
```

the only workaround I can think of (that does not require forking or monkeypatching anything) would be to first update the whole queryset so the jsonfield is set to something valid, ie:

```
qs.update(name_of_the_field={})
qs.delete()
```

But this won't preven other issues with your data being inconsistent, so the real solution is obviously to clean up your whole dataset.

Comment: Didn't think of that, brilliant. And I don't care losing this because it will be delete just right after.
Updates have been pushed but we still have crappy old data so the point of the whole command was just to get rid of those nasty pieces. Thanks

Comment: Well if the point is to clean up the database, then it's probably the simplest solution indeed ;)